# Deploy API Management with Function App - Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management

I have got an Azure HTTP Function App deployed via Terraform, I would like to manage access to the HTTP function via API management. I can see how to created API management via Terraform, however I cannot see how to marry my function app upto my API management. Via the console this is very simple. How can I do this via terraform?

Comment: What does this mean? 'Via the console this is very simple.' What is the result of this? Does it produce APIM Policies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the terraform code to add your Azure function as a backend to Azure API Management:

```
resource "azurerm_api_management_backend" "example" {
name = "sample-backend"
resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.example.name
protocol = "http"
url = "https://${azurerm_function_app.example.name}.azurewebsites.net/api/"
credentials {
header = {
"x-functions-key" = "${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.example.default_function_key}"
}
}
}
```

Refer to [Royarin blog article](https://royarin.blogspot.com/2021/01/import-functionswebapi-in-azure-api.html) for more information on adding the Functions or Web API as an API in Azure APIM as backend.